# Python: Searching from File, getting largest number

Tags: python

So the program must find the player with the highest score in each level.
I have a text file called `playerScores.txt` which has the name, the score, and the level every line. Example in format `Player:Level:Score`:

```
Starplayer,1,19
```

The program must find the highest scorer for each level, so for level 1 it must find the highest number. This is what I got so far:

```
playerData = open("playerScores.txt", "r") #opening file with data
level = input("Game Level?") # asking for which level
for line in playerData: 
    if(line.split(",")[1] == level):
            print(level)
            print(line.split(",")[0])
            print(line.split(",")[2])
```

This finds the number after the second comma for each level but it finds all the numbers and not just the highest number.

Comment: This is not a question but a "please do my work for free" thread...

Comment: From the comments to each of the answers, it seems like you're just looking for working code that you can use without even attempting to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is convert the scores from strings to numbers. Like this:

```
for line in playerData: 
    sname, slevel, sscore = line.split(",")
    sscore = int(sscore)
```

Notice that I also just called `split` once instead of 3 times, and gave meaningful names to the results instead of just calling them `[1]` and so forth.

---

If you're using Python 2.x, that `level = input("Game Level?")` is going to convert your input to an `int`, so you'll need to convert each `slevel` to an `int` as well. However, you really, really, really shouldn't use `input` in Python 2.x; a better fix would be to switch that to `raw_input`. But you might want to convert to an `int` anyway, so if someone types "I don't know what to put here" they get an error instead of no result. :) So, let's show that:

```
level = int(raw_input("Game Level?")) # asking for which level
```

(If you're actually on Python 3.x, leave the `raw_input` as `input`, but still add the `int` around it.)

And then, inside the loop:

```
    sname, slevel, sscore = line.split(",")
    slevel = int(slevel)
    sscore = int(sscore)
```

---

Next, you can keep track of the highest number as you go along:

```
hsname, hslevel, hsscore = None, None, -1
for line in playerData: 
    sname, slevel, sscore = line.split(",")
    slevel = int(slevel)
    if slevel == level:
        sscore = int(sscore)
        if sscore > hsscore:
            hsname, hslevel, hsscore = sname, slevel, sscore
```

And then you just print it out at the end:

```
print(hslevel)
print(hsname)
print(hsscore)
```

---

If you want to get clever, you can do this by transforming the iterable of lines into an iterable of triples, then calling `max` on the result:

```
triples = (line.strip().split(",") for line in playerData)
level_triples = ((n, l, s) for (n, l, s) in triples if int(l) == level)
highscore = max(triples, key=lambda triple: int(triple[2]))
hsname, hslevel, hsscore = highscore
```

---

Either way, we're not storing anything other than the name/level/score for the highest score seen so far. (In the first version, that's explicit; in the second, we're just building lazy iterators and calling `max`, so it happens implicitly.) That's great if you really only want to do one lookup and then quit.

But if you're going to do multiple lookups—say, you want to have a menu where the user can ask for level after level, or you just want to print out all the levels' highscores—you'd do better to convert the data into a format that makes it easy to do the lookups, as in [Kasra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29890024/908494).

Comment: This is what I get everytime after typing a level. 
None
None
-1

Comment: @OliverBeck: Oh, that's because you're using `input` under Python 2.x, which is converting your `level` input to an integer. Let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for such tasks :

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
playerData = open("playerScores.txt", "r") #opening file with data
level = input("Game Level?") # asking for which level
for line in playerData:
    l=line.split(",") 
    if(l[1] == level):
            d[l[1]].append(int(l[2]))
for i,j in d.items():
   print 'level{}:{}'.format(i,max(j))
```

In preceding code you loop over the split lines and store the levels as the keys of your dictionary and append the relevant score to its value that is a `list`.

And after creating the dictionary loop over the dictionary and print the `level` and `max` of scores.

Or you can use `dict.setdefault` method :

```
d={}
playerData = open("playerScores.txt", "r") #opening file with data
level = input("Game Level?") # asking for which level
for line in playerData:
    l=line.split(",") 
    if(l[1] == level):
            d.setdefault(l[1],[]).append(int(l[2]))
for i,j in d.items():
   print 'level{}:{}'.format(i,max(j))
```

Also as a more efficient way you can use `csv` module to opening your file :

```
import csv
d={}
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in spamreader:
        d.setdefault(row[1],[]).append(int(row[2]))

 for i,j in d.items():
     print 'level{}:{}'.format(i,max(j))
```

Comment: If you're going to do this lots of times (as in your example, iterating over all the levels, instead of just doing one level and then quitting, as in the OP's example), building the right data structure like this to make it easy is definitely useful.

Comment: @abarnert sorry i couldn't understand your comment!! :)

Comment: @abarnert But i this using a linear solution is better than multi-generator expression approach with `max` and a key function!

Comment: Better how? Your solution is linear time, linear space; both of my solutions are linear time with a smaller constant and constant space. And I think this is less novice-friendly than the first version of my answer. If you need to make lots of searches against the same data, then building the dict is worth doing. But if you only need to do it once, building the dict just to throw it away is a waste.

Comment: @abarnert Yes your first solution is liner and as i say i mean using `generator-expression` in your last solution! but not only that i mean all of the commands in your last solution! and about the dictionary yeas its not efficient for lots of searches against the same data.

Comment: When you write a sequence of generator expressions, it's still lazy and efficient. [David Beazley explains it a lot better than I could.](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) It's effectively doing the same work as my first version—more abstractly, but just as efficiently. Also, your dictionary _is_ efficient for lots of searches against the same data, certainly better than my solution… it's just that building the dict is not efficient for _one_ search.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for useful link! i think i got your mean! and you dot my up-vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read all data in a appropriate data structure. Then you can ask for any level you want:

```
highscores = {}
with open("playerScores.txt", "r") as scores:
    for line in playerData:
        player, level, score = line.split(',')
        level = int(level)
        score = int(score)
        if level not in highscores or highscores[level][1] < score:
            highscores[level] = player, score

level = input("Game Level?") # asking for which level
print(highscores[int(level)])
```

Comment: if level not in highscores or highscores[level][1] < scores:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < _io.TextIOWrapper()

Comment: sorry, one `s` too much.

Comment: Sorry if its obvious but I can't find it, where is there an S too much?

Comment: it was `scores`, now it is `score` and everything works.

Comment: Hello, if I were to ammend the program you wrote so it would write the scores for levels 1-15 instead of just writing the scores for the level inputed . I thought I could paste the program 15 times by setting the input to each level but would there be a quicker? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Nvm, I found a simple solution! Thanks anyway :)